# How to access to a inherited protected field of a object

Tags: c#, .net

I have two classes from a reference DLL. Here is a simplified figure of them.

```
public class A {
    protected object a;
}
public class B : A {
}
```

now I have a instance of class B, and I want to access to the protected inherited field a, how can I make it?

Comment: Access it from within B, or through a reference to an instance of B?

Comment: Protected members can be accessed within derived class, but not outside of the class. You should be able to access `a` member inside class `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have no rights to change class A and B and still you want to access the protected property you can use reflection as follows :

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class A {
    protected string a;
}
public class B : A {
}

public class Test{
  static void Main() {
      //get the type of the class
       var b = new B(); 
        Type type = b.GetType();
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        // get the field info
        FieldInfo finfo = type.GetField("a", bindingFlags);

        // set the value 
        finfo.SetValue(b, "Hello World!");

        // get the value
        object someThingField = finfo.GetValue(b);
        Console.WriteLine(someThingField);


  }
}
```

Comment: @displayname Using reflection is not a great idea, it works. I would go with Mat Sz approach, if i really need to expose it from the B class i would create a public `Read only property` inside the B class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it from outside of the class, you will need to create a new class that inherits from B and then manually expose the field.

Like so:

```cs
public class C : B
{
    public object exposedA
    {
        get { return this.a; }
    }
}
```

`protected` means that the field is private to everything except for classes that inherit from the original class.

Comment: Not really. You do not need the C class. He can do it from  the B class similarly.

Comment: @panoskarajohn I assumed the B class also comes from the library.

Comment: What library? The OP has it as public class B. So I do not understand what you are trying to say. Your answer is correct, but you do not need the extra class.